# Can I persist an ActorRef in a persisted event in Akka Persistence?

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

In some cases, an actor may need to keep an ActorRef for later communication with other actors. I'm wondering if I can put the ActorRef into a persisted event so that I can recover the reference to an Actor later on?

Comment: Yes, you can. See this example for instance: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/persistence.html#replies

Comment: I have carried some tests and it turns out you cant. You will get akka.actor.EmptyLocalActorRef during recovery phase